# Why is there an exponential in the radial component of the hydrogen electron orbital wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen, orbitals

The solution for the Schrödinger equation for an electron in a (spherically symmetric) potential well shaped like $V=1/r$ is described by a wave function of the form $\Psi_{nlm}(r, \theta, \phi) = R_{nl}(r)\,\Theta_{lm}(\theta, \phi)$.

In the case of $l=m=0$ we only have to worry about the radial component, which (specifically for l=0) is the product of an exponential function in r and a polynomial in r, like $R_n(r) = e^{-r/a}\, P(r)$. These polynomials (of increasing order as $n$ increases) are such that they are orthogonal to one another over $[0, \infty) $ if multiplied by $e^{-r/a}$.

But why is that exponential there at all? I associate exponentials with, you know, exponential growth and decay, that kind of thing, but to me there seems to be little in the "problem statement" that would imply that you'd encounter an exponential here. Of course, you might say, "It's there because it solves the relevant partial differential equation", but I'm looking for a more intuitive explanation.

Bonus points if you can relate it to the Gaussian $e^{-x^2}$ term that occurs in a free electron's wave function, initially well-localised, diffusing over time. (The only difference between the two situations being the presence of the $1/r$ potential.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any bound solution in QM looks like a decaying exponential sufficiently far away from the center of the attracting potential.

The intuitive physical meaning of this can be understood if you remember that under very general conditions which are typically satisfied at a sufficient distance (WKB approximation) the wave function of a particle can be roughly written as $\psi (\vec{r}) \propto \exp (- i \vec {p} \cdot \vec{r}/\hbar)$, here $\vec{p}({r})$ being particle's momentum at a given location $\vec{r}$ which can be found from the obvious semi-classical relation:
$$\frac{p(r)^2}{2m} + V(\vec{r}) = E$$
where $V(r)$ and $E$ are the potential and total energy of the particle respectively.
Now if your particle is bound around some point in space (e.g. like an electron near atomic nucleus) and with some binding energy $E_B=-|E_B|$, then if you potential is in a certain sense sufficiently local, then in the regions where $|V(r)|<<|E_B|$ the local momentum $p(r)$ can be formally found to be given by $p^2 = 2mE_B = -2m |E_B|$. Note that this means that $p$ is imaginary now and the wavefunction must therefore depend on $r$ as:
$$\psi(r) \propto \exp \left(- \frac{\sqrt{2m|E_B|}}{\hbar}r\right)$$
recovering your decaying exponent.
To summarize, the exponantially decaying wavefunction is not a feature of the Kepler problem in QM but is a general phenomenon when it comes to bound states at asymptotically large distances from the attraction centers.

EDIT: Coming to the "bonus question". By the same token as above you can see that for a parabolic potential $V(x) = \frac{1}{2} m\omega_0^2 x^2$ (again, sufficiently far from the origin)
$$(p(x))^2 \approx  -2mV(x) = -m^2\omega_0^2 x^2$$
hence
$$\psi(x) \sim \exp(-|p(x)|x/\hbar) = \exp\left(-\frac{m\omega_0}{\hbar} x^2\right)$$

Comment: Ah, so you might say it's analogous to the exponential in the absorption of radiation by a medium. E.g. the fraction of sunlight that makes it to a depth of $r$ in the ocean before being absorbed. As in, the electron only makes it so far out from the potential well.

Comment: In some sense yes, the decay of radiation intensity due to absorption can be described by the imaginary part of refractive index. However, if we think about light propagation, a closer analogy would be the evanescent field (on the "air side") of a beam experiencing total internal reflection.

Answer (score 7):

For fixed energy, there is a region where classically the particle cannot access because there the kinetic energy would be negative: if $E=T+V$, then $T=E-V$ so if $V>E$ then $T$ would be negative.

In this region the Schödinger equation looks like
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi= (E-V)\psi
$$
so the right hand side is negative.  The resulting DE is thus
$$
(\text{negative coefficient})\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \psi(x)= (\text{some other negative coefficient})\psi(x)
$$
and the solution to this is an exponential, i.e. $\psi(x)\sim e^{\pm\lambda(x) x}$.  You need to eliminate $e^{\lambda(x)x}$ because it goes to $\infty$ at $x\to \infty$ so you're left with $e^{-\lambda(x)x}$. Now, there are several types of exponentials, and it's only in the details of $V$ that you can know if you need to choose $e^{-\lambda x^2}$ or $e^{-\lambda x}$.  The specific form is determined by the behaviour of $V$ at large values of the argument.  In the harmonic oscillator for instance one has $e^{-\lambda x^2}\phi(x)$ while, in your case of the hydrogen, you have $e^{-\lambda r}\phi(r)$.

Physically this is sound: because classically the particle cannot have negative kinetic energy, the probability of finding the particle there should be rather small, and this is true if you compute this probability in the limit of large quantum number $n_r$ or $n$, where the particle behaves more classically.

Answer (score 1):

> But why is that exponential there at all? I associate exponentials with, you know, exponential growth and decay, that kind of thing, but to me there seems to be little in the "problem statement" that would imply that you'd encounter an exponential here. Of course, you might say, "It's there because it solves the relevant partial differential equation", but I'm looking for a more intuitive explanation.

*Very* qualitatively, I absolutely expect the wavefunction to be large in the general vicinity of the nucleus and small at great distance.  If that does not inspire a direct mental jump to asymptotic decay to zero, then consider the properties of wavefunctions:

- they are normalizable, so they must have vanishingly small values in most of space, but be nonzero in at least some places.
- all their partial derivatives are continuous, so they could not be constant on any contiguous region of space with nonzero volume unless they were constant everywhere. That would require a sharp(ish) elbow -- a discontinuity in the partial derivatives -- where the WF changes from *approaching* the constant value to *maintaining* it.  In particular, they cannot achieve normalizability by being identically zero outside a finite region.

Between those two, it should be clear that any WF must approach zero asymptotically in most of space.

Does it need to be an *exponential* decay? That may not be as intuitive, but it certainly should not be a surprise.  If you think a bit more about the shape a WF must have -- smooth and finite everywhere -- I think you'll at least see that exponentials are a good candidate.